# jquery selector to select find imgs but NOT images in child divs

Tags: jquery, css

I have html in the style of:

```
<div>
   <div><img /><img /></div>
   <textarea />
</div>
<div>
   <img />
</div>
<div>
   <textarea />
</div>
```

I noticed that a previously used selector will not work correctly.

```
$(item).find("input[type!='checkbox'],textarea,img").andSelf().csS("height", x);
```

as it selects the imgs and in the subdiv.

What is the jquery command not search the children of "div" tags to allow it to select all textareas, inputs NOT checkbocs and child imgs (not in divs)

Comment: was thinking to append to the selector:  *.not("div > img")*

Comment: `.csS("height", x)`? There is no `csS` jQuery method, do you mean `css`?

Comment: @kevinB Sorry, you should not change the codes!

Comment: @undefined it's obviously just a typo, otherwise he would be getting a pretty obvious js error, !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `...textarea,>img")...` however that is being depreciated. I would do it this way:

```
$(item).find("input[type!='checkbox'],textarea").css("height",x)
    .end().children("img").andSelf().css("height",x);
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it so that the parent div wraps around everything?  Since i was using .andSelf() it was hardcoding it i believe.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by making the parent div wrap around everything... Since it is a parent div, doesn't it by definition already wrap around everything?

Comment: Seems the code did not have height set to auto, but instead hardcoded components.

Comment: Do you really need the `.andSelf().css("height",x);` without it, it would use whatever height it has (set or none). Otherwise, you would have to set it's height equal to x + the top and bottom padding of `item` and top and bottom margin of the child element (or set it to auto i guess)